# Why does Flask not load HTTP1.1 correctly?

Tags: flask

I am trying to make a simple application using `Flask`. The files of the application are in a directory `app` and `Flask` uses this directory as the root directory.

In the directory `app`, I have a subdirectory `templates` that contains an html file. This file contains the lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js-css/stylesheet.css">
<script src="js-css/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="js-css/javascript.js"></script>
```

In the directory `app` I have a subdirectory `js-css` containing these three files.

I use `PyCharm`. When I start up the application, it shows (as expected)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" D:/python/genealogie/genealogie.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When in `FireFox` I go to the address `localhost:5000`, the templates file turns up, but clearly the stylesheet was not found. `PyCharm` shows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2019 09:39:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2019 09:39:48] "GET /js-css/stylesheet.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2019 09:39:48] "GET /js-css/jquery-3.3.1.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2019 09:39:48] "GET /js-css/javascript.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2019 09:39:48] "GET /js-css/javascript.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

It seems that the problem is due to an incorrect loading of `HTTP/1.1`. I will highly appreciate if someone can explain what is going on here and to overcome this problem.

Comment: I don't see how this is HTTP/1.1 related...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set `static_folder` (full path to where your files physically are) and `static_url_path` (url path to that directory) config options when creating flask app.

Refer to flask API reference for details: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/

I usually put all my static assets under `web` directory, as in `web/js`, `web/css` etc. Then I have my `static_folder=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'web')` and `static_url_path=''`. Then in my templates I can refer to these assets like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. After having studied your links, I decided to use the standard static folder and now everything runs fine..